# JOCL: why use buffers?

Tags: opencl

Given a `float[n] inputdata` to pass to the OpenCL kernel, could anyone enlighten me on the difference between the following three ways to pass this to the kernel:

A)

```
cl_mem input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR Sizeof.cl_float * n,
        inputdata, NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, i, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(input));
```

B)

```
clSetKernelArg(kernel, i, Sizeof.cl_float * n, Pointer.to(inputdata));
```

C)

```
cl_mem input = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_options_here, Sizeof.cl_float * n,
        NULL, NULL);
clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, input, CL_TRUE, 0, Sizeof.cl_float * n, 
        inputdata, 0, NULL, NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, i, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(input));
```

?

Have I understood correct that the difference between A) and C) is that C) copies the entire array once at the start and then works on-GPU with it, while A) has to load its data on-the-fly? So A) is good if one needs only a small portion of an array, and C) is the way to go if you use the entire array anyway?

And what about B)? Is it more like A), more like C), or still something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you cannot pass huge amounts of parameters. There is an upper limit on the size of all parameters (typically in the 50 KiB range -- you can query it with `clGetDeviceInfo` and `CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE`). With Method a and c you can pass much larger buffers (hundreds of megabytes.) a is not helpful for OpenCL 1.1 and lower, as the buffer will be still copied usually, but with OpenCL 1.2, you can avoid one copy if your host and device is the same (i.e. you are running a CPU OpenCL runtime for instance.)

Comment: So the size limit is the *only* difference? E.g. as long as B) works, there's really no reason to use A) or C)? And will it be faster than A) and C), or slower (e.g. when host-changing array contents) or are they truly equivalent?

Comment: Semantics and size. If it's some buffer, you should use a buffer, as the maximum parameter size may be as small as 256 bytes (!). Careful with poster mfa, he's wrong, as you cannot easily pass data into __local; you can only set the size of a __local buffer at kernel invocation time (you still need to copy the data into __local.) I would use a, if you only need to get data onto the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

What each method does:

A) This method uses the host's buffer to store the data. When you don't want to copy the data to the device, but want to use it in-place. I believe that this is only possible on CPU devices, but I am not entirely sure.

B) Passes a __global* type to your kernel. Use this for limited amounts of data. Beware that for the __local/NULL version of this that performance can be greatly (and negatively) effected by large numbers of work items / groups. Size is limited to CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE. Passing NULL will result in __local* type, and the limit is CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE.

C) Use this when you have a large (ie larger than the limit of method B) amount of data that your kernel will need. This copies the data from your hosts's buffer to the device's buffer. If your data is ready for use, you can  use the mem flag CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR to copy it when you create the cl_mem buffer, and skip the clEnqueueWriteBuffer call.

Comment: Could you provide me a reference for the claim that B) automatically passes the variable as __local? This sounds quite strange, as it doesn't seem to be the case for non-array variables.

Comment: That's wrong: See the documentation of http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html. If you pass null as the pointer, and only pass the size, then you specify the size of a local buffer (pointer MUST be null, so you cannot allocate & copy data into a local buffer at kernel invocation time.)

Comment: My mistake, It needs to be NULL to be __local. In that case, you are bound by CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE. Otherwise, it's __global, and the limit is CL_DEVICE_MAX_PARAMETER_SIZE.

Comment: Just wanted to expand on A); This makes sense when the OpenCL device is sharing RAM (as in integrated GPUs often does). :)